# How to use FileSystemWatcher in F#

Tags: f#

I want to watch a directory for file changes (create, edit, rename, delete) and do something, such as calling a function, when a change is detected. From what I can tell, [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) should do this. However, there is no sample code for F# on the documentation page, and elsewhere on the web seems scarce as well.

From what I've found, the following is at least part of the answer:

```
let fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher()

fileSystemWatcher.Path <- @"C:\temp" // I'm actually using a variable here
fileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter <- NotifyFilters.LastWrite
fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents <- true
fileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories <- true

fileSystemWatcher.Changed.Add(fun _ -> printfn "changed")
fileSystemWatcher.Created.Add(fun _ -> printfn "created")
fileSystemWatcher.Deleted.Add(fun _ -> printfn "deleted")
fileSystemWatcher.Renamed.Add(fun _ -> printfn "renamed")
```

That doesn't actually *do* anything, however. [Some posts](http://fpish.net/topic/None/59981) seem to have an Async loop to react to events, but if I use the code snippets from there F# tells me that `Async.AwaitObservable` is undefined.

I'd appreciate it if someone could provide a complete example of FileSystemWatcher's correct usage.

Comment: What operating system are you running on? And if you're not running Windows, which version of Mono are you using?

Comment: Forgot to include that - Arch Linux; `mono --version` says "Mono JIT compiler version 3.12.0."

Comment: P.S. In console apps one needs to set `fileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject` to null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me in FSI.

Drop the `NotifyFilter` bit - you're overwriting the default settings (which do include `LastWrite` anyway), and some of the events you care about are not being raised. `NotifyFilter` is an antiquated enum-flag-style field, so you can add a new value there like this:

```
watcher.NotifyFilter <- watcher.NotifyFilter ||| NotifyFilters.LastWrite
```

You don't need an async loop per se - in the example you linked to it just replaces the standard event handlers that you are already using. But if you want to use `Async.AwaitObservable`, look up FSharpx on nuget.

Comment: The problem was that the directory I was watching wasn't the one I was editing files in (they're named the same thing and have similar structure), so of course nothing would happen. Your changes and the code I posted do in fact work.